# ConfuserEx: MSBuild Integration: "An IO error occured"

Tags: confuserex

I am trying to integrate ConfuserEx into the build task of my solution. I need to do this so that the obfuscated DLL is the one that is picked up by the NuGet package.

I am using the MS Build Integration to do this but I keep getting the following error

`An IO error occurred, check if all input/output locations are readable/writable.`

I am running Visual Studio as an admin, and have admin rights on the machine, have checked the read only status of the folder so I'm not sure what it is complaining about.

I am using version 1.6 of Confuser.MSBuild package and here is the relevant part of my .crproj file.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Obfuscate>true</Obfuscate>
    <ConfuserReplaceOutput>true</ConfuserReplaceOutput>
</PropertyGroup>
```

and here is the .crpoj file.

```
<project outputDir="Redacted Path\confused" baseDir="Redacted Path" xmlns="http://confuser.codeplex.com">
  <module path="obj\Debug\net462\RedactedName.dll">
    <rule pattern="true" inherit="false">
      <protection id="anti debug" action="remove" />
    </rule>
  </module>
</project>
```

This all works correctly from ConfuserEx GUI, just the MS Build Integration failing, but I plan to automate this using pipelines.